# Accessing Wordpress on Wamp3 from my cell phone over wifi

Tags: server, localhost

Cell phone -> Android - Browser Chrome

Server -> Wamp 3.3

Windows Firewall open to \Wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\bin\httpd.exe

httpd-vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot C:/Wamp/www/mysite
    <Directory  "C:/Wamp/www/mysite/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I can access local.mysite.com on my server's browser. Local Wordpress installation works ok.

I cannot access  local.mysite.com from my cell phone.

I can access 192.168.1.2:80/mysite/ from my cell phone but it doesn't load wordpress' index.php, it loads my custom 404 page.

I've been messing with wp-config.php file but no dice.

Question: Is there anyway I can access local.mysite.com from my phone?